# How to access Pivot.TitleTemplate as UserControl?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm-light

Subj, how can i get it?

```
        <controls:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <mainPivot:MyUserControl Name="MainPivotHeader"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
```

Tried to find it via VisualTreeFinders, but it sees only pivot item.

UserControl shows a picture, but it depends on user. During first initialization, it is empty, because user is not yet logged in. So, i'd like to force its update.

I can use mvvm light messaging, but i'm looking for self-sufficient components. This forcing is rare, so i dont want to use messaging here.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot Call its Refresh() method. It has Loaded() event, but it is called before necessary data is initialized during the first login. So i'd like to force updating. Also, edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the Title property of the Pivot to a property on a ViewModel. Your DataTemplate would then have it's DataContext already set to that object. When you need to refresh, you call some method on that object.

Example

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyTitleObject _titleObject;

    public MyTitleObject TitleObject
    {
        get { return _titleObject; }
        set
        {
            _titleObject = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TitleObject");
        }
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        TitleObject = new MyTitleObject();
        // or refresh values directly on the object
    }

    ...
}
```

You xaml for your Pivot would need to following

```
<controls:Pivot Title="{Binding TitleObject}">
</controls:Pivot>
```

When you want to refresh, call the refresh on the viewmodel.

Comment: But i already have Title's DataTemplate, which is UserControl with its own TitleViewModel. Maybe i can get TitleViewModel from VM locator, and update its data?

Comment: Well, but then i'd be needed to access VM from VM, which is better to do via messaging.

Comment: If the DataContext of your Pivot is `ViewModel` then you would not need a separate viewmodel for the title. Any other properties that are need would go in the `ViewModel` class. f course you would name it something more relevant.

Comment: I'm using this UserControl on the other pages. I can bind it to base ViewModel, so all my ViewModels would have theese bindings. But i also have lots of VMs, where this UserControl is not used.